# Bookshelf Node js issue: A valid target model must be defined for the equipment_component hasMany relation

Tags: node.js, join, bookshelf.js

I want to use join in bookshelf.

I am getting the error: "A valid target model must be defined for the equipment_component hasMany relation" for the below settings

component.js

```
'use strict';

const Base = require('./base');
const Equipment_Component = require('./equipment_component');

function Component(bookshelf) {
    return Base(bookshelf, {
        tableName: 'component',
        equipment_component: function(){
            return this.belongsTo(Equipment_Component, 'component_id');
        }
    })
}

module.exports = Component;
```

equipment_component.js

```
'use strict';

const Base = require('./base');
const Component = require('./component');

function Equipment_Component(bookshelf) {
    return Base(bookshelf, {
        tableName: 'equipment_component',
        component: function(){
            return this.hasMany(Component);
        }
    })
}

module.exports =  Equipment_Component;
```

The query looks like:

```
await equipment_component.where({'equipment_id': '7'})
.fetch({withRelated: ['component']})
.then(function(result){
   console.log(test.toJSON());
})
```

base.js looks like:

const shared = require('../shared');

> ```
> function Base(bookshelf, params, plugins) {
>   let model = bookshelf.Model.extend(Object.assign({
>     hasTimestamps: true,
>     permittedAttributes: function() {
>       return bookshelf.knex(this.tableName).columnInfo();
>     },
>     diff: (a, b) => {
>       let diff = [];
>
>       for(let i in a) {
>         if(i == 'updated_at') continue;
>
>         if(b[i] != a[i]) {
>           diff.push([i, a[i], b[i]]);
>         }
>       }
>
>       return diff;
>     },
>     setExtraContext: function(ctx) {
>       shared.setExtraContext(ctx);
>     },
>     logMessage: function(message) {
>       let obj = {};
>       obj[this.tableName] = this.serialize();
>       shared.setExtraContext(obj);
>       return shared.logMessage(message)
>     }
>   }, params), plugins);
>   return model;
> }
>
> module.exports = Base;
> ```

Need some insight here.

Comment: What does `Base` look like?

Comment: I've added the base.js

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular dependency problem.

In version 1.0.0 of Bookshelf the preferred way to create new models is to use `bookshelf.model('ModelName', { /* ... */ })` instead of `bookshelf.Model.extend()`. This will use a central registry when accessing models preventing the circular dependency problem.

The easiest way to achieve this is to modify your base to call this at the end like so:

```js
function Base(bookshelf, name, params, plugins) {
  let model = bookshelf.Model.extend(Object.assign({
    // ...
  }, params), plugins);

  return bookshelf.model(name, model);
}

module.exports = Base;
```

You then have to change all your relations to use model name strings instead of direct object references, e.g.:

```js
function Equipment_Component(bookshelf) {
    return Base(bookshelf, 'Equipment_Component', {
        tableName: 'equipment_component',
        component: function(){
            return this.hasMany('Component');
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I tried something else and forgot to remove model. Let me update it.
But still it is not working, getting the same error.

Comment: I'll update the answer, because the problem is clearer now, but I still need confirmation on something. I added the comment above.